# Class not found from dependency jar

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi, xssf

In my project I use apache.poi libs to work with excel files. I have dependencies on:

- apache.poi.ooxml_3.15
- apache.poi_3.15
- apache.poi.ooxml_schemas_3.15

jars. So during compilation there are no problems.
On runtime:

```
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    ...
    Workbook workbook2003 = new HSSFWorkbook(); //1
    Workbook workbook2007 = new XSSFWorkbook(); //2
```

line 1 works correctly, while line 2 throws exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook cannot be found by org.apache.poi.ooxml_3.15.0
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 41 more
```

`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` is located in `apache.poi_3.15` but during runtime jvm tries to find it in `apache.poi.ooxml_3.15`. Not sure why?

Maybe someone can help me to fix this problem.

More details about project:
 - Ide: eclipse neon.1|
 - it is e4 project
 - java 8

Answer (score 2):

Since `XSSFWorkbook` works on OOXML schema, it loads the `Workbook` class from `poi.ooxml` jar. You might be getting this error because `xmlbeams` jar is also required as dependency in runtime.

**Update**

`commons-logging`, `commons-codec`, `commons-collections`, `log4j` jars are also required for `poi`. Please check if you have imported them. All of these `jars` are already there in `poi-bin-3.15-20160924` file which you might have downloaded. Please see [this page](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for prerequisites of various components.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: added both jars, but still get exeption

Comment: @Bublik Please check the update. Also check the order of imported jars `poi` -> `poi.ooxml` -> `poi.ooxml_schemas` , if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The library have probably other runtime depedencies that are needed for second case. Can you try to setup the project as a maven project ? It should solve your problem since maven takes care also for dependencies of your explicitly defined libraries.